# UITableView Not Updating On Insert/Scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, ios8

I have a UITableViewController, and in the controller I have the following code:

```
// Update the table view
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([self.transcripts count] - 1) inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

// Scroll to the bottom so we focus on the latest transcript
NSUInteger numberOfRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
if (numberOfRows) {
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(numberOfRows - 1) inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the UITableView is never updated. I've verified that my transcripts Array is increasing in size, and that `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called. I'm stumped. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** here's my IB tableView definition if that helps.

```
<tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" allowsSelection="NO" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="MXJ-GP-L47">
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
    <color key="separatorColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
    <color key="sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
    <prototypes>
        <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="none" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="MessageCell" id="sdU-aF-ZZy">
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="sdU-aF-ZZy" id="7IE-xs-uAL">
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
        </tableViewCell>
        <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="none" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="ImageCell" id="Lac-k8-MMs">
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="Lac-k8-MMs" id="IVD-DR-azV">
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
        </tableViewCell>
        <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="none" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="ProgressCell" id="efc-wO-XPu">
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="efc-wO-XPu" id="7j1-RG-rHz">
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </prototypes>
    <connections>
        <outlet property="dataSource" destination="Eyi-tC-JyD" id="AM2-Xx-Xsd"/>
        <outlet property="delegate" destination="Eyi-tC-JyD" id="Tkb-ac-NHB"/>
    </connections>
</tableView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting you must call

```
- (void)beginUpdates;   // allow multiple insert/delete of rows and sections to be animated simultaneously. Nestable
```

And after inserting is done call

```
- (void)endUpdates;     // only call insert/delete/reload calls or change the editing state inside an update block.  otherwise things like row count, etc. may be invalid.
```

Comment: I tried that. It didn't make a difference. I don't even see the rows when I manually scroll afterwards.

Comment: Try and remove one animation either the animation for inserting either the animation for scrolling , the two animations may interfere. But you must call begin/end updates on tableview.

Comment: Same result, with and without beginUpdates/endUpdates. I added my IB tableView definition to the question if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Basically, I use custom views for each cell, but I didn't have the custom views tagged or embedded in the cell's Content View.